# Python os.getenv() returning incorrect value on Windows - Is there an alternative?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, environment-variables

I'm using os.getenv() to return a password to a python script. The password contains a capital I and when I save this as an environment variable it is saved correctly (after saving if I go to edit it and copy and paste it into notepad it shows correctly). The python os.getenv() method however returns the capital I as a lowercase l. Has anyone else encountered this and/or is there any other method I can use to return an env variable?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no alternative, and this can't be Python's fault.

On Windows, the `os.environ` mapping is initialised from the [`_wenviron` global](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/environ-wenviron?view=vs-2017) when Python starts. (Environment variables are given to a process when it starts running, if you changed the environment variables later on then you need to restart your process). The structure Windows gives Python is UTF-16, with keys always uppercase, values opaque Unicode text.

Python decodes the data from UTF-16 to Python `str` objects (`unicode` in Python 2), and creates a the `os.environ` mapping from that. That mapping then just maintains the uppercase nature of the keys, nothing else is changed. `os.getenv` is a helper function that uses `os.environ.get()`. There is no other API available or needed.

If you see unexpected data, you either made a mistake with how you set the variable, or you have changed the variable after Python already started. It's easy enough to mix `I` (capital India) and `l` (lowercase Lima); it is best just to avoid confusable characters like those and `0` (number zero), `O` (uppercase Oscar), `1` (number one) altogether.